# Excel VBA: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method with "as Range"

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime-error

Please help debug: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

I'm not sure why my statement Set ImCrazy = .Find("Total") is not working.

"Total" is part of about 23 cells.  I basically want to find each one, select it, then move 1 cell over and input a function, etc.

```
Sub Utilization()

'Utilization Macro

'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+u

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim knt As Integer
Dim ImCrazy As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        .Range("$A$4:$F$800").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="0"
        ActiveCell.Offset(6, 1).Range("A1").Select
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Range("b2"), .Range("b" & lastRow)). _
               SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                         "0"
                         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"

        .Range("$A$4:$F$800").AutoFilter Field:=3
        .Range("a1").Select
        .Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Set ImCrazy = .Find("Total", xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)

        If Not ImCrazy Is Nothing Then
            ImCrazy.Offset(0, 1).Value = "=SUM(R[-" & knt & "]C:R[-1]C)"
            ImCrazy.Offset(0, 3).Value = "=(RC[-1]+RC[2])/RC[-2]"
        Else
            MsgBox "'Total' not found'"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I also need this to be a loop, so that it will continue checking for the word "Total"

In summary 
 1. I need help with the run-time error
 2. I need help constructing the code to repeat looking for "total" and inserting the functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the correct syntax of [Range Object Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).
So below line will not work because:

```
Set ImCrazy = .Find("Total", xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)
```

1. It doesn't specify the range. Using dot `.` means that you're trying to call a property or method from `ActiveSheet`. That results to `Error 428` since worksheet object really doesn't have `Find Method`.
2. You did not supply the argument names and yet you didn't include `After` argument. Even if you correct the object reference, it will still fail.

Try this:

```
.Cells.Find("Total") ' This finds a cell that contains "Total" in the ActiveSheet
```

Now, if you need to find all occurrences, then you'll have to use a loop and [`FindNext` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196143.aspx).